# PHP cUrl : HTTP Error 400 while The Browser Displayed Correctly

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-400

**URL:**

You can see the url in [Here](http://pastebin.com/N8y1XYfL) (I put the url in the pastebin because the url is quite long).

**Curl & Header :**

```
$header=array();            
$header[]="Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$header[]="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate";
$header[]="Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$header[]="Connection: keep-alive";


$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
```

**Result:**

> Error 400--Bad Request
>   From RFC 2068 Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1:
>   10.4.1 400 Bad Request

The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications."

**The Browser when go to the URL directly without curl:**

Displayed Nicely.

Comment: try removing all of the headers and see what happens. then add them back in one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are problems with your URL, chances are it was computed wrong.

If you're generating that long URL from your script, make sure it's the right one.

The reason is that if you try deleting stuff, let's say you end up with `https://wftc3.e-travel.com/plnext/garuda-indonesia/Override.action`, you will see that accessing this page ends up in a 400 error.

I hope this helps.

---

**/edit:** this works, so it's probably `$url`.

```
<?php

$url = "https://wftc3.e-travel.com/plnext/garuda-indonesia/Override.action?SITE=CBEECBEE&LANGUAGE=ID&EMBEDDED_TRANSACTION=FlexPricerAvailability&ENCT=1&ENC=BE37D8CC9CE37D25AB7C16ED9DC32B9AB70052C76CC99D6460FB6990C37619D08A86D19D12DB2E39B1C2572C7C97A890E4D0CA079A35CB075FC284C469128F210A361D6121DEF1E64C3E153CCF855158302AA41136F317A8F143E4A2DDFEF68DB413BD337613EF92A4809626A4E3CB107A5666859C612C388539292CD16A1FF421C143F7D74A504845EBC98B1476E79EB32DFB32E46B43ADF0B514FB472B0258C41F696441043714660B3493F3395E8329B93A0C4E7EA3E1E466025EAE4AE2562754B6324C4C4CFEDC3CA4548A17AAFA500FC0A331F1FB1B770FE91E31B88D5C391DA66B00A5AD8F83D02BBB962F35B6BAAAAE34984EF07693352467B3AC7C1F62D8AA70B791C71CAC7AD4E4744563A096471F0CF79FF28425EFD39C2A58D0D52F279632268E3FBB1217DB8DF5A61181D466B62CA13CC7044EC9E90A550DC3CFD3A28EBC4FB9FC451D0C34BA94E7CF46B5FF1C9E1ADECA8EAE477B1112AA911E8826C07311B033F5D3AD39F26814A7399072805235049E856C9BC9E9C0819AC596471F0CF79FF28425EFD39C2A58D0D5A7B93A6BBADB799F3B3B95A975D76E523BD3C538C3B91D308FC57D8F84ACD46D57A25DAD2528B4486D0DC651B85D1DD27680F4762A813920C0D7DBF02676A659F6479A9F3A48B7202F10A44379467113DC817B3F3908F5F21D13389934D53CCDC787523D2953A5401152E090735051220AEA4FC852F0A20BCD957F8F2BDA35C0C9AC95AF6075C2923C1FA881D3D3C0484BA6740A4CCF8CBB8FB1E0C2FC9C1B0E35764D079EA758ED28405DDE81CB538B69A5C75758DA45C03F45EEF0D75B6E714ABED40ED5E467D99F4CBBFEAAAC28EB7BD54AA4E28454445AE822E53EDC3DAD7634FDBC01F64DB410A450D54EECBE4F9BB8BB8FA9E2B8CFE4CD88019D3BCAE97A041BDB6C72AD195FB68212FEC44CE587C5CA13B74686FD62FEE6AA43C4FA3DE765A4EAA2034043E2CB24F5BD0B48F771F51FDD8197D0C0B6DF85DD8D5EBED594F80B56C7963080333C519C67B88961921D48431AF465CA9A94060E8DC600EE3BDBAFEB22FBE9E105C6F386A0580A6F6E7FC39BC0D3F12A253DD73581FC7C6FA4EF58293CEE6869B817EE1F1D4801A3282C9F857924158FB6D2EFC7A02057155B69A8271F69B754AE7D978062AD01AC449A3D598CFB37921ECC4932CFE4A19A891C29A0B1C234E3950520529F97DDD2FA5793ADEF0FC1D327C3E38C77455FF12AF99DF582CB6BE66F9FA601DF00AD3EBE281CCC3B9BA63A47860E793A6D5002486A06345EB691B2521491F8694797EE0EFEC1C90C082B815D23EE0E46E4CA6A9EB06EB1483FC07C1D7B17818AA8B20F16223C113ACBB81B628BE6EDDA4E96D559E7A7BA9A1BCD31FB3FEEAE509704B54B426646A42CA6F7C75E85BBB32FA49E60102E76D13F7961343025E44CF14705EF7424EC3578B294BF87D34DB49040CBCEABC06B466033A4AB5BEF9660F69B68BFB71206446F8A8EDECD068C8EAE159840BE226495914996D001BC6872525FB8D5A43A545CCF106EA9E823CEEE64F6955AAF3340E15DE72ED4D1865D63C9D85C3B0CC627381311163D08103D86C0392C1FDCD7065892EF3519C6A802940125B7D6C167C10E3D4750BC762DE1F10A15C0C8FD23A77E1E1310AE9CE073CA809773C21794EC1F190E868C513B83CB35EDBDDC31297078D472BE9A37C2F70A1BE31C0A5042E89214851AC675AEB34690ADED5AFA187CE56AE5D3270B07B6986EF5FEF05AB2C4BF44F5281CC3779E98EAE5F090AA07928D4FFEC8A893799F5BB3BA57ED47422E7532DB4F570F7E2CF8F2C9FF76CE87DBEA84738C535794EFD373A1080D7E12CB3B7C37AA566D663E54CCCBDCFE9E7970B61AB40F02A528F2107E9DEBD6B0795D766FB16AA71E0BF1091F2F897BBE39B1E11B3B610B5DF0CF98ABDE6A9B1D5C5784144D68A4629FDD409B7D6349D888162741633A718ED89B555EB147B67A79B06055E02BFBCEC56CD768BEFD38391AE4B7F13CD3AC6D9FADE73C1C2E313B83FDE3FAB3D60BE111D43EFA7565D5614427F7F0CBD7913C0E9496FA2978868C1D983C14212C987D6B0E38BEF1701B4120E6147BB88E776E1C05574475A7E44F4D11963189DB5BA6EEDB6E514D543BA8CA23A216AF3C5E876E99BCBD46F3B066A5BCE4FDBAA0CA012DFEF2A256652B8DE8AF04A0C27E58379BB1768602DBE55717B38AF3EDB8570FD4A9CC80D7D27A41AA2AF727C833A46583C3955E5BD0CE289BAF1F9AFD9415619A00EE2E965A46AE7891A4F3A303F5E44183DD542F13";


$header=array();            
$header[]="Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$header[]="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate";
$header[]="Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5";
$header[]="Connection: keep-alive";


$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.2; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
$x = curl_exec($ch);

die(($x));
```

Comment: The url is not deleted and that full url (including the get parameters) is the url used in curl. I think the problem does not reside in the url, because when we use the browser to go to the url directly, the browser could displayed the content correctly.

Comment: And you're sure that's the whole code that you're using? Could you at least try `$ch = curl_init(trim($url));`? Or try taking all the parameters in the URL out one by one, see what's required for that error to appear. I tried stuffing in extras but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I've already tried trim or urlencode for the url, but still doesnt work. The url looks valid, though. In my view, I tnink the problem is not about the url.

Comment: If you update your question with the whole code I'm pretty sure we can sort it out.

Comment: is this really works or I am mistaken here? because I've added `CURLOPT_ENCODING` to 'gzip' but still no changes in result.

Comment: It really works, I've hardcoded the url in `$url`, copy-pasted from pastebin but it doesn't show here on SO. I was `var_dump`ing the return from `curl_exec` and it was showing gibber because we're accepting gzip, that's why I've added encoding.

Comment: You are right @GRIGORE-TURBODISEL..Finally I can figure it out. There are some encoded character in my variable (amp;) that I didn't see before. And +1 for the gzip, because I haven't realize it before.